# Why my app is asking for permissions not configured in Azure AD App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a very basic project authenticating user on my Office 365 directory.

When I access it, I have this consent screen:
[image]

I'm a bit surprised because, I've removed all the permissions to my application:
[image]

The request URL has this permissions:

```
&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20User.Read.All%20Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared
```

Why does the application ask for this permissions even if they are not set in AzureAD?

Comment: How did you login? Could you provide the request url? Could you make sure you are using the same client id?

Comment: I've updated the post with the scope part.

Comment: Did you use auth code flow?

Comment: Yes, very basic web app. If not authenticated go to azure ad login screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between v1.0 endpoint and v2.0 endpoint. When use v1.0 endpoint, we will use `resource` instead of `scope`. All the permissions should be listed under **API permissions**.

However, when use v2.0 endpoint, we can ask for permissions dynamically. It doesn't matter if you have permissions under API permissions. When you add the permissions to scope, you will see the consent window.

Comment: Pretty clear, thanks a lot. Now, permission listing is only needed for permissions requiring Admin Consent?

Comment: Answer to my question is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison